# $E[\log(X)]$ when $X$ follows binomial

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I am looking for solution and some references for the following expectations:

1. $E[\log(X)]$ when $X$ follows binomial with parameters $n$ and $p$, i.e. $E(X)=np$
2. $E[\log(a+bX)]$ where $E(X)=\frac{a}{(1-b)(1-e^{-a})}$

Comment: Domain of support includes 0. Log[0] will pose a 'problem' ...

Comment: @wolfies there are some special cases to this... remember n and p aren't specified.

Comment: self-study?! this looks like homework, if so please add tag.

Comment: This is not home work.

Comment: I am trying to do some simple research. We can take any n and p.

Comment: If you alrealy know n and p, I think you can use the formual $E[log(X)]=\sum_{k=1}^nlog(k)\binom{n}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}$ to calculate the expectation directly. and  log (0) is undefined as wolfies pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

1. From the law of the unconscious statistician

   $E(t(X))=\sum_{i=0}^n t(i)\,p(X=i)$ where $p(X=i)={n\choose i}\,p^i\,(1-p)^{n-i}$.

   Note that $p(X=0) = (1-p)^n$, so that *unless* $p=1$, $P(X=0)\,>\,0$; call this value $q$, say, and hold $p$ and $n$ fixed.

   Writing $E(t(X))=t(0)\,P(X=0)\,+\,\sum_{i=1}^n t(i)p(X=i)=t(0)\,q\,+\,c$, say, when $t$ is the logarithm, $\log(0)$ is undefined -- but let's briefly consider what happens if we look at $\lim_{\delta\to 0}\,t(0+\delta)$:

   $E(t(X))=\lim_{\delta\to 0}\,t(0+\delta)\,q\,+\,c$

   Now in this particular case, $t(.) = \log(.)$, so $\lim_{\delta\to 0}\,t(0+\delta)\,q\,+\,c\to -\infty$. If however, you construct some limiting case where $p\to 1$ as $n\to \infty$ and $\delta \to 0$ in some particular ways so that $q$ and $c$ also vary, you might perhaps be able to construct other limits, but even if that were to work, the cases where it would make sense to do so would not be typical. I doubt you mean to do anything like that, so you're back to "undefined".
2. here $t(x)=\log(a+bX)$. Here, if for example we take $a>0$ and $b\geq 0$ then we have a case where the expectation will be finite.

   I don't see an obvious simplification of the expectation

   $E(t(X))=\sum_{i=0}^n log(a+bi)\,{n\choose i}\,p^i\,(1-p)^{n-i}\,,$

   however* -- I'd tend to compute it directly if I needed it.

   * outside of pulling $(1-p)^n$ out the front and writing $(\frac{p}{1-p})^i$.

Maybe there's some algebraic simplification I don't see but it's not clear that it would be helpful even if there were.